Multi-line `tcbox`
Is there any way to create a tcbox (tcolorbox pacage) with multiple lines? Of course, paragraph mode doesn't make sense in this context, but having multiple lines nonetheless does make sense.
\tcbox{Hello\\World!} % This should display over two lines.


Can you add some image or screenshot of your requirement for more clarity?

er ... yes. there's nothing special here. almost every box I create with tcolorbox has multiple lines. please complete your code so we can compile it to reproduce the issue. snippets are useless.

@cfr I wrote tcbox rather than tcolorbox, however, which has more restrictions.

@Noldorin yes, I mentioned that in my answer, but most things are still supported. only a couple of more complex things like breaking aren't. unless you are trying to avoid tikz, which you didn't mention?

@cfr I think tikz may be interacting badly with some of the contents of the box, but let me check. Thanks for your answer.

@cfr If you're curious, here's the long list of errors I get when I use the tikznode option (the tcbox is for the contents of a node/individual using the genealogytree package). https://pastebin.com/VFRX9yQw

@Noldorin I don't really need to look ;). genealogytree uses tikz, does it not? nesting tikzpictures is not supported. the best option in that case is to add the frame/background into the picture. failing that, you either need a method which works with tikzpicture contents. or you want to box the contents first. if you do that, you can also measure it, so you aren't restricted to \tcbox.

@Noldorin I suggest asking a new question with a more realistic example and linking this one. you didn't mention this in this question and that requirement moves the goal posts rather a long way out of the stadium we started in .... and please give a complete mwe if you do so.

@cfr Yes, because I wasn't sure it was relevant originally. People tend to underestimate the difficulty of making a good MWE (or making one at all). But I agree, that's probably the way to go now.

@Noldorin making an MWE is just a mechanical process when you want to solve some specific problem. but it gets harder when you are asking a how-to, I agree, because there's no algorithm for figuring out what's necessary.

Right... It can be very time-consuming, in certain cases, at the least.

There are some restrictions on \tcbox, but nothing to prevent the contents spanning multiple lines.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tcbox[tikznode]{a\\b\\c}
\end{document}



Thanks. I thought the tikznode option might be a bit hacky for this purpose, but evidently not

@Noldorin looking at the manual, I don't think so. examples seem to use it in similar ways. if you need paragraphs, I would use one of the other tcolorbox environments, though. is there some particular reason to avoid them?

I need a (coloured) box that automatically fits its contents.

@Noldorin but don't the other commands/environments do that? why does it have to be \tcbox? if you need paragraph breaks, can't you use one of the other options rather than \tcbox? (or does only \tcbox adjust width? I don't remember trying to do that, so not sure - usually, I want fixed width boxes, so I don't need it.)

Oh, not at all; that's the main distinguishing feature of tcbox, whereas the others have fixed sizes (though they can adapt the size of the content text).

You can wrap tabular, which also allows to set the alignment with respect to the outer text.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  mlouter/.code={\def\tcboxmlouter{#1}},
  mlinner/.code={\def\tcboxmlinner{#1}},
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tcboxml}{O{}m}{%
  \tcbox[mlouter=c,mlinner=c,#1]{%
    \expanded{\noexpand\begin{tabular}[\tcboxmlouter]{@{}\tcboxmlinner@{}}}#2\end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Some text 
\tcboxml[on line]{Hello\\World!}

Some text
\tcboxml[on line,mlinner=l]{Hello\\World!}

Some text
\tcboxml[on line,mlinner=l,mlouter=b]{Hello\\World!}

Some text
\tcboxml[on line,mlouter=t,mlinner=l]{Hello\\World!}

\end{document}

In the optional argument, any tcolorbox key relevant for \tcbox can be used.

For paragraphs, you can use varwidth. The default 0.8\columnwidth is just some random value, it could be made more precise by looking at the parameters (left as exercise).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\tcbset{
  mlouter/.code={\def\tcboxmlouter{#1}},
  mlinner/.code={\def\tcboxmlinner{#1}},
  pmax/.code={\def\tcboxpmax{#1}},
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tcboxml}{O{}m}{%
  \tcbox[mlouter=c,mlinner=c,#1]{%
    \expanded{\noexpand\begin{tabular}[\tcboxmlouter]{@{}\tcboxmlinner@{}}}#2\end{tabular}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tcboxp}{O{}m}{%
  \tcbox[mlouter=c,pmax=0.8\columnwidth,#1]{%
    \begin{varwidth}[\tcboxmlouter]{\tcboxpmax}#2\end{varwidth}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Some text 
\tcboxml[on line]{Hello\\World!}

Some text
\tcboxml[on line,mlinner=l]{Hello\\World!}

Some text
\tcboxml[on line,mlinner=l,mlouter=b]{Hello\\World!}

Some text
\tcboxml[on line,mlouter=t,mlinner=l]{Hello\\World!}

\noindent
\tcboxp{Some random text that possibly wraps
  across lines at maximum width, let's add some more.}

Some text
\tcboxp[on line,mlouter=t,pmax=6cm]{Some random text that possibly wraps
  across lines at maximum width, let's add some more.}

Some text
\tcboxp[on line,mlouter=b,pmax=6cm]{Some random text that possibly wraps
  across lines at maximum width, let's add some more.}

\end{document}



Interesting solution, thank you! I think I may need to use paragraph mode inside a tcbox though (contrary to what I originally thought), and thus a \varbox will be the solution.

@Noldorin I added support for varwidth.

That's a nice wrapper macro, cheers. Incidentally, here's the error log when I use \tboxml to show the content (which is a node/individual using the genealogytree package). https://pastebin.com/jRyNLtYM
